# content to sit in the middle of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 for my website and have created divs for each section to be 100% no matter how you manipulate the browser window etc. I wish to have my content sat in the middle of that at all given times heights and widths.

I am really struggling to get it right.

Here is my code:

```
<div id='imgDiv'>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 300px;">
        <a href="#imgDiv3">Smoothscroll</a>
        <center>
            <h1 style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: 300;">Header</h1></center>
        <center>

            <h2 style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300; padding-top: 30px;">My name</h2>           
        </center>
    </div>  
</div>


html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;  
}
#imgDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #1ABC9C; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: The `center` element was deprecated on HTML4.01, and isn't even present in the HTML5 specification. It's unnecessary and you should avoid using it. Remove it and simply give your `h1` and `h2` elements a style of `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want...

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/5420/)

HTML

```
<div id='imgDiv'>
    <div> <a href="#imgDiv3">Smoothscroll</a>    
         <h1>Header</h1>    
         <h2>My name</h2> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
#imgDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #1ABC9C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: #FFF;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
#imgDiv > div:first-child {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

you should also remove the `center` element and move your styles into your stylesheet instead of being inline.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `margin auto for left and right side`

```
#imgDiv {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:100px;
 ....
}
```